# Selenium find elements using xpath and limiting the search based on a parent class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find all the `hrefs` within the center box of this URL: https://www.bytesin.com/software/Antivirus-Spyware-Apps-4/. I'm using this xpath:

> //div[@class='st']/a

But all the elements of `st class` will be returned. How can I modify the xpath so that I only get `hrefs` of `st class` that have `fcbox top`
as their parent class?
I tried to do it using this xpath but it does not work. It returns this error saying that this xpath does not return a set of nodes.

> //div[child::div[@class='fcbox top']]/a and //div[@class='st']/a

Actuallly there are three set of links(hrefs) in this page.(I want to exclude top 10 freewares and latest updates from the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you need.

```
//div[@class='fcbox top']//div[@class='st']/a
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]